# Lightbox works locally but cease to work on googledrive

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, lightbox

I plan on using this lightbox called ekko lightbox for my portfolio gallery. I'm following this tutorial here, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8TcXHpdyqm0

It works on my end locally, a great easy tutorial to follow, however when I upload this onto googledrive the lightbox cease to work. I inspected in google chrome and found no errors. :/ I plan on using host gator to host my site later but for now I'm testing on googledrive. Should I be worried it's not working on googledrive or ignore this? I have NO issues getting the lightbox to work locally and I'm seeing no errors.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dark.css">
</head>
<body>


<div class="col-sm-3">
    <a href="my_bmw.jpg" data-toggle="lightbox" data-title="My BMW" data-footer="A the fsdlkfldk">
    <img src="my_bmw.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script> 
<script src="lightbox.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).delegate('*[data-toggle="lightbox"]','click', function(){

event.preventDefault();
$(this).ekkoLightbox();

});
</script>
<script  src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">         
</script>   

</body>


</html>
```

here's the css he provided

```
.modal-backdrop {
width: 100% !important;
min-height: 2000px !important;

}


.modal-backdrop.in {
-webkit-opacity: 0.95;
-moz-opacity: 0.95;
opacity: 0.95;
background-color: #333333;
}
.ekko-lightbox .modal-content {
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
-webkit-border-radius: 0;
-moz-border-radius: 0;
border-radius: 0;
border: none;
background-color: transparent;
}
.ekko-lightbox .modal-header {
border: 0;
padding-left: 0;
padding-right: 0;
}
.ekko-lightbox .modal-header .close {
-webkit-opacity: 0.5;
-moz-opacity: 0.5;
opacity: 0.5;
color: #fff;
text-shadow: 0;
font-weight: 100;
margin-top: 5px;
}
.ekko-lightbox .modal-header .close:hover {
-webkit-opacity: 1;
-moz-opacity: 1;
opacity: 1;
}
.ekko-lightbox .modal-header h4.modal-title {
font-weight: 100;
color: #fff;
padding: 0;
}
.ekko-lightbox .modal-body {
padding: 0;
}
.ekko-lightbox .modal-footer {
-webkit-opacity: 0.9;
-moz-opacity: 0.9;
opacity: 0.9;
border: 0;
color: #fff;
font-weight: 100;
padding: 0;
}
.ekko-lightbox-nav-overlay a {
-webkit-opacity: 0.9;
-moz-opacity: 0.9;
opacity: 0.9;
text-shadow: none;
}
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mixed content unsecured stylesheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32808170/mixed-content-unsecured-stylesheet)

Comment: you are right! It's fixed. I need to add https not http.