# Mixed content unsecured stylesheet

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap 3 website that uses lightbox from http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

The lightbox works fine from the local drive but as soon as I upload it onto googledrive, I get this...

The lightbox does not work and I get these errors. Here are my links, is there an order issue with jquery links?

Thanks,
Chris

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Jquery is not loaded..first fix that

Comment: refer to your `.css` and `.js` files with `https://` (or  just `//`) instead of `http://`. This is a server settings issue on googledrive, they demand `https`.

Comment: jlocker, Its in there. It's the first script tag above all else at the bottom before the closing body tag. jquery 2.1.1

Comment: davidkibrad, whats the difference?

Comment: @ChrisBrennan - see this excellent question / answer(s) -> [**Does https prevent man in the middle attacks by proxy server?**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/8145) It is a security issue.

Comment: davidkonrad, it worked. Thank you and thanks for the helpful link. :)